# SonKitapTarihi: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id no

Tags: field-update, after-trigger

fail is:SonKitapTarihi: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: [] Trigger.SonKitapTarihi: line 19, column 1

[image]

my code is :

```java
trigger SonKitapTarihi on Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c (after insert) {    
     Ziyaretciler__c zyrtci = new Ziyaretciler__c();
    //list<Ziyaretciler__c> zyrtList = [SELECT Id, Name, Kitap_Aldigi_Son_Tarih__c FROM Ziyaretciler__c];
    
    List<Ziyaretciler__c> yeniList = new List<Ziyaretciler__c>();
    date sontarih;

    if (Trigger.isinsert) {
        for(Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c kitapverme :trigger.new){
            if(kitapverme.Kitabi_Alan_Kisi__r.id == zyrtci.id){
                sontarih = kitapverme.Kitap_Verilen_Tarih__c;
                zyrtci.Kitap_Aldigi_Son_Tarih__c = sontarih;
                yeniList.add(zyrtci);
            }   
        }

        update yeniList;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i create a new record on Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c object, i want to update Kitap_Aldigi_Son_Tarih__c field on Ziyaretciler__c object.
Kitap_Aldigi_Son_Tarih__c <--Kitap_Verilen_Tarih__c

Comment: Related objects are not accessible via the `__r` relationship field in a trigger. Since you just do `Xyz__r.Id` you can instead use the equivalent `Xyz__c`. Also, you try to use the `Id` for your `zyrtci` but this record is unpopulated with any field values.

Answer (score 1):

The simple explanation for your error is that in `yeniList`, you're adding `zyrtci` but you never set `zyrtci.Id` or query for it. DML update requires that the records have the Id populated (or a field marked as an "External Id" with a unique value).

You never set `zyrtci.Id` or query for it, so there is no Id. The DML update thus fails.

Some additional helpful information is what Phil W says in the comments. Related data is not automatically accessible in trigger context records (if you need to use more than one period/dot/full-stop, to get at the data, then it is "related data"). Since you're only using the Id though, instead of needing a query, you can get the "visitors" id via `kitapverme.Kitabi_Alan_Kisi__c`

Going off of some quick Google translate, and the code you have so far, it looks like you're attempting to update the "last given date" for a specified book on your "visitors" object.

I'll assume that you're not looking for the createdDate of the most recent `Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c` record, nor the newest/latest "book assignment/issued date" because all of those should be possible using a rollup summary field (and do not need a trigger).

I assume that you just want the "book assignment/issued date" of the most recent `Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c` record.

In that case, I think that the trigger you have is reasonably close. The main points for you to consider here are:

- You want to create new `Ziyaretciler__c` (Visitor__c) instances in each iteration of your loop
- You need to set the Id for each `Ziyaretciler__c` record (and trigger.new does contain that information in `kitapverme.Kitabi_Alan_Kisi__c`
- Using a `Map<Id, Ziyaretciler__c>` will be helpful

```java
trigger SonKitapTarihi on Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c (after insert) {
    // Using a map makes it easy to detect and handle duplicate data
    Map<Id, Ziyaretciler__c> yeniMap = new Map<Id, Ziyaretciler__c>();

    // At this time, this if is not necessary because your trigger is only
    //   running on insert.
    // I'll leave this as is though, because distinguishing between events is
    //   generally a good idea
    if (Trigger.isinsert) {
        for(Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c kitapverme :trigger.new){
            // The "if" statement you were using previously doesn't make much sense.
            // My best guess is that was how you were attempting to detect if you
            //   had already seen a "Visitor" in this run of the trigger and needed 
            //   to update the "book assignment/issued date"
            // A map is the more appropriate choice here
            yeniMap.put(kitapverme.Kitabi_Alan_Kisi__c, 
                // The SObject constructor can take name = value pairs
                // It's a fast and convenient way to set fields
                new Ziyaretciler__c (
                    Id = kitapverme.Kitabi_Alan_Kisi__c,

                    // No need for a separate variable, you can just assign the value
                    //   directly
                    Kitap_Aldigi_Son_Tarih__c = kitapverme.Kitap_Verilen_Tarih__c
                )
            );
        }

        update yeniMap.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for answer. I solved the problem like this:
trigger SonKitapTarihi on Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c (after insert) {
 list<Ziyaretciler__c> yeniList= new list<Ziyaretciler__c>();
 date sontarih;
 if (Trigger.isinsert) {
       for(Kitap_Veris_Islemi__c kitapverme:trigger.new){
           Ziyaretciler__c zyrtci= new Ziyaretciler__c();
            zyrtci.id=kitapverme.Kitabi_Alan_Kisi__c;
                sontarih=kitapverme.Kitap_Verilen_Tarih__c;
            zyrtci.Kitap_Aldigi_Son_Tarih__c=sontarih;
            yeniList.add(zyrtci);
            
           } update yeniList;
    }